# Switching to a language and reload the ViewController in IOS

Tags: ios

I am using the code below to switch to a language:

```
-(void) switchToLanguage:(NSString *)lang{
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:lang, nil] 
          forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
[sliderViewController refreshView];
}
```

I am not sure if it is right. After that, in the refresh view function of sliderViewController:

```
-(void)refreshView{
slideLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"To Menu", @"To Menu");
slogan.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Categories", @"Categories");
}
```

But it doesn't work. Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the `AppleLanguages` key only works in your `main.m` file, before `UIApplicationMain` is called. If you try and change its value at any other time it will not work.

If you want support for changing the language at runtime, you will have to roll your own localization functions.

Comment: Hmm i see. What do you mean by rolling my own localization?

Comment: I mean you will have to write your own XYXLocalizedString which checks which language is currently set, and reads the appropriate .strings file to fetch the string value.